# Pythonで商用ソフトを作りたいのですが

Tags: python, windows, compiler

こんにちは

Python2.7で商用ソフトを作りたいのですが以下お教え下さい。
①ソースコードは全て開示しなければいけないのでしょうか？
②逆コンパイルさせないコンパイルはできないのでしょうか？
③Pandas等複数のモジュールを使っているのですが、コンパイルしてexe
形式にするにはこつがあるのでしょうか(以前、Scipy,Numpyをpy2exeした
ところうまくいなかった記憶があります。うろ覚えなのですが。。。)。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 4):

> ①ソースコードは全て開示しなければいけないのでしょうか？

いいえ、開示する必要はありません。

GPLでライセンスされたモジュール等を使用している利用はこの限りではありません。

> ②逆コンパイルさせないコンパイルはできないのでしょうか？

それはPyhtonに限らずあらゆる言語において不可能です。

[Cython](http://cython.org/)とか[pyminifier](http://liftoff.github.io/pyminifier/)を使って解析を若干難しくすることはできます。

> ③Pandas等複数のモジュールを使っているのですが、コンパイルしてexe形式にするにはこつがあるのでしょうか

主なライブラリを使用するときの注意点がここにまとめられています。

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WorkingWithVariousPackagesAndModules

Answer (score 0):

> ①ソースコードは全て開示しなければいけないのでしょうか？

使っているライブラリ等のライセンスで決められていない限り、この必要はありません。

> ②逆コンパイルさせないコンパイルはできないのでしょうか？
>   ③Pandas等複数のモジュールを使っているのですが、コンパイルしてexe形式にするにはこつがあるのでしょうか

Python で作られたプロジェクトを、依存ライブラリも含めてコンパイルするには py2exe 以外にも方法があります。[「Python のプログラムを実行可能バイナリにコンパイルするには？」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/42597/19110)をご覧ください。

Python ではコードを守る需要がそこまでなく、あまりツールが発展していない印象です。難読化や暗号化を用いてリバース・エンジニアリングを難しくすることはできると思います。["How do I protect Python code?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/261638/5989200) をご覧ください (一番上の回答だけでなく、その他の回答も参考になるかと思います)。