# Python のプログラムを秘匿しながらアプリを販売したい

Tags: python

自分で作成したPythonプログラムを誰にでも使えるかたちで、個人のネットショップなどで販売するにあたって,

- 製作したプログラムの譲渡の仕方
- コードなどを相手に見えないようにするには
- 販売するファイルにパスワードを設定するには

以上のことを知りたいです,よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: どのレベルの「方法」なのか詳しいことをお聞きしたいです。つまり、具体的にどの部分ができなさそう、あるいは、よく分からないと感じていらっしゃいますか？　これには、ネットショップの作り方が分からない、金銭授受の方法が分からない、プログラムの渡し方が分からない、など、いくつかの側面があると感じます。

Comment: nekketsuuu様。ご指摘ありがとうございます、内容の方に追記いたしました。誠にありがとうございました。

Comment: 「難読化」や「バイトコードへの変換」などいくつかの方法が考えられますが、そもそもPythonはソースコードが読める状態で実行できる「スクリプト言語」なので、コードの秘匿性を保ちながら販売を見据えて配布は中々難しそうです。

Comment: こんなQ&A [Pythonで商用ソフトを作りたいのですが](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/8738/python%E3%81%A7%E5%95%86%E7%94%A8%E3%82%BD%E3%83%95%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8A%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C) がありますのでご参考に。

Comment: kunif様。ご回答いただきありがとうございます、参考にさせていただきます。

Comment: @cubick Python のプログラムはインタプリタで動かすのが主流ではありますが、コンパイラが無いわけではありません。特に、Python から C へトランスパイルして C コンパイラに渡すツールがいくつか存在します。別に投稿してみたので、ご参照下さい: [Python のプログラムを実行可能バイナリにコンパイルするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/42597/19110)

Comment: 本家 Stack Overflow での類似質問です: ["How do I protect Python code?
"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/261638/5989200)