# C++で書いたwindowsアプリケーションにpythonを埋め込む

Tags: python, python3, visual-studio, selenium, winapi

C++でwin64 apiを使ってガワだけ作ったアプリケーションにpythonを埋め込みたいのですがどうすればいいのでしょうか?
Pythonがインストールされていない環境でも動かしたいので、アプリケーションの中にPythonを同梱したいと考えています。
Windows x86-64 embeddable zip fileというものを使えば実現できそうなのですが、visual studio 2017 communityで使いたいのですが使い方（どうすれば埋め込めるようになるのか)がわかりません。

[image: example_figure]

上のようなwindowがあり、実行をクリックするとseleniumのテストが開始され、停止を押すと、停止するようにしたいです。

また、seleniumのテストはpythonで書かれたものがすでにあるため、C#などで書き直すことは極力避けたいです。

`LoadLibrary`を使って`python3.dll`を読み込めばよいのでしょうか?
この使い方のドキュメントがあまりなく、よくわかっていません。

さらに、標準ライブラリを使うために、このzip内の`python36.zip`を展開したディレクトリをvisual studioのソリューションに追加したいのですが、drag dropしても追加されません。

OS:windows 10 Home
Visual Studio Version: Visual Studio 2017 Community

Comment: 使用された言語はC++でなくCですか？

Comment: C++です。C++らしいことを全くしていない(Classとかつかってない)のでCと書いてしまいましたが実際はC++です。

Comment: "Windows x86-64 embeddable zip file"はPythonのインストールパッケージ（Pythonをインストールするためのファイル)です。　質問に書かれている「Pythonを埋め込む」とは、どういう状態(状況)を意味しているのでしょうか？

Comment: [他のアプリケーションへの Python の埋め込み](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/extending/embedding.html) のようなことがしたいのでしょうか？

Comment: https://docs.python.org/ja/3.6/using/windows.html#embedding-python で説明されている`ネイティブコードで書かれ、時々スクリプト言語のようなものを必要とするようなアプリケーション`をpython3.dllを使って作りたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

たまたま「Community♦ によってトップに表示されました。」ので。遅い回答ですが。

別方向のアプローチとして、この程度のGUIならば、Pythonに入っているTkInterで作成し、
PyInstallerとかPy2exeなどでパッケージとしてまとめれば、悩むことは少ないと思います。

それだけではなく、GUIライブラリも、exe化ツールも選択肢はいっぱいあります。

[【わかりやすく解説】PythonのGUIライブラリを比較10選 おすすめはどれ？](https://hajipro.com/python/python-gui-best)

[Python のプログラムを実行可能バイナリにコンパイルするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/42597/python-%e3%81%ae%e3%83%97%e3%83%ad%e3%82%b0%e3%83%a9%e3%83%a0%e3%82%92%e5%ae%9f%e8%a1%8c%e5%8f%af%e8%83%bd%e3%83%90%e3%82%a4%e3%83%8a%e3%83%aa%e3%81%ab%e3%82%b3%e3%83%b3%e3%83%91%e3%82%a4%e3%83%ab%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ab%e3%81%af/42598#comment43780_42598)

[webdriverprefs.json not found - pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702621/webdriverprefs-json-not-found-pyinstaller/25709423#25709423)
[Testing Tkinter or Selenium for Tkinter (Python recipe)](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/580751-testing-tkinter-or-selenium-for-tkinter/)

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft のブログ](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/26/cpython-embeddable-zip-file/)を参考に試してみましたが、結論としてアプリケーションの開発にはWindows x86-64 embeddable zip fileは必要ありません。Python の通常のインストールパッケージの中に、インクルードファイルやリンクに必要な .lib ファイルも含まれています。

では Windows x86-64 embeddable zip file は何かというと、アプリケーションを作成した後に配布する際に、一緒に配布すべき最小限の Python のファイルを集めたものです。標準のライブラリしか含まれていないので、追加のライブラリが必要な場合は、どのように追加ライブラリを配布するか、別途検討しなければなりません。

Comment: Pythonがインストールされていない環境で実行できるようにするには`C:\Program Files\Python36\include`の中身と `C:\Program Files\Python36\libs`の中身をプロジェクトに追加すればよいということでしょうか?

Comment: @KiYugadgeter 開発環境の構築と、成果物の配布とは分けて考えてください。Visual Studio でアプリケーションを作成すれば exe ファイルができますが、exe ファイルだけをコピーしても、作成したアプリケーションは動きません。Windows x86-64 embeddable zip の中身もすべて一緒にコピーしなければなりません。