# pythonのスクリプトファイルをwindowsのexeにしたい

Tags: python, python3, windows-10

現在、python3.5でpythonのアプリケーションを作成しています。
それを、最終的にはWindows10上で動くexeファイルにしたいと思っています。
どうすればWindows10上で動くexeにできますでしょうか。
わかる方、教えて頂けないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `python exe化` でググって見つけた http://kconcon3.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/01/22/230000 が参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: @ishihara-flicfit さん、こういうことでしょうか？ https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/42597/19110

Comment: [https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/42597/python-のプログラムを実行可能バイナリにコンパイルするには/42598#42598]も参考になるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: @Haru さん、ご存知かもしれませんが、既存の質問で解決していると思ったときには「重複」でクローズ票を投じることもできます :)

Comment: @nekketsuuu はい。知識としては知っております。投票しようかどうかは迷いましたが、一応情況をながめてみる事にしました。@nekketsuuuさんのQ&Aには、実行可能バイナリと書いてある一方、こちらはexeと質問に書いてあり、同じことなのは同じことなのですが、このワードで調べる人もいるのかなと思ったりしましたので、色々迷いがありました。まだ慣れてないものですいません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

私はpyinstallerを使います
http://www.pyinstaller.org/

pipを使ってインストールするために
pip install pyinstaller

それ で
pyinstaller filename.py

Comment: みなさんありがとうございます。

Comment: Python2.7,pyinstallerでできました。